# Can we get facebook friend list of a email id without using login with facebook feature

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Is there any way to get friend list of a emailid?.

I want to get facebook friend list of a email email id like 'test@gmail.com' without login into facebook with this email id.
Is it possible??

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: Please don't post a question that you haven't tried to solve. You should attempt to solve it yourself first. If you have tried, you can then include your code and research in your question to show what hasn't worked for you. It makes your question easier for others to answer too!

Comment: I created a app on facebook and downloaded facebook-php-sdk from github. but i did not get any function in facebook-php-sdk to get friend list of a email id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. Users are identified by an ID on Facebook, not their email.

Facebook PHP SDK is "just" PHP library that help you to use Facebook Graph API, go [read its doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api) to lear all what you can and can't.